# Java Script Gets Error in IE11

Tags: javascript

I have a 2008 Chrysler service manual for my car. It used to open OK in XP but no matter what I do it won't run in IE11. Here is the script of the itcToc.js where I get my error:

```
     if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")
sessionTabNameIE();
else if(navigator.appName == "Netscape")
sessionTabNameNS();
```

It faults out on this line with some error that it was unable to find the SessionTabName. Any help sure would be appreciated. Thanks, Bob.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please post the exact error you're getting and the `sessionTabNameIE` function as well. As a side note that i just discovered the `appName` for IE11 is `Netscape`

Comment: It would be better if you can put the javascript code too including the  <script> tags

Comment: Geeze, years after browser sniffing was finally recognised as a seriously flawed strategy, this stuff still lurks in the corners…

Answer (score 0):

In IE 11, using JSON to display navigator will like this:

```
{
   appCodeName: "Mozilla",
   appMinorVersion: "0",
   appName: "Netscape",
   appVersion: "5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Tablet PC 2.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko",
   browserLanguage: "zh-TW",
   constructor: { },
   cookieEnabled: true,
   cpuClass: "x86",
   geolocation: { },
   language: "zh-TW",
   maxTouchPoints: 0,
   mimeTypes: { },
   msManipulationViewsEnabled: true,
   msMaxTouchPoints: 0,
   msPointerEnabled: true,
   onLine: true,
   platform: "Win32",
   plugins: { },
   pointerEnabled: true,
   product: "Gecko",
   systemLanguage: "zh-TW",
   userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Tablet PC 2.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko",
   userLanguage: "zh-TW",
   vendor: "",
   webdriver: false
}
```

Therefore, you need to see any keywords in userAgent or appVersion which only IE has. Also, other browsers, such as chrome, firefox, opera...etc, are the same way